# Python passing arbitrary non-caller/non-self class instance to C

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, typeerror

I'm implementing a generic priority queue that takes `int`s as keys and *any* class instance as elements; call these *anything*s as nodes. The algorithm is to be prototyped in python but implemented in C++. I'm trying to figure out the python-interfacing part. Here's the C++ code

**queue.c++**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class PQueue
{
public:
    PQueue()
    {
        Q = std::vector<PyObject *>();
    }

    void insert(PyObject *node)  
    {
        Q.push_back(node);
        std::cout << "Added a node" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<PyObject *> Q;
};

extern "C"
{
    PQueue *PQueue_new() 
        { return new PQueue(); }
    void PQueue_insert(PQueue *self, PyObject *n)   /* This fails */
        { self->insert(n); }  
}
```

Here's the corresponding python prototype:

**queue.py**

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libqueue.so')

class PriorityQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.PQueue_new();

    def insert(self, n):  # this fails
        lib.PQueue_insert(self.obj, n );
```

The variable `n` is an arbitrary class instance representing a node. I'd like to access the member variables of `n` using *PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs*, but I'm unable to do so because of the following error:

```
lib.PQueue_insert(self.obj, n );
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

I get that python classes are not C primitives but the fact that `PyObject` exists makes me believe that something like this should be possible.

Comment: ctypes can convert it as `ctypes.py_object(n)`, but you need to keep a reference in Python to prevent the object from becoming unreferenced and deallocated while your C++ library is using the `PyObject *` pointer. Also, to actually call methods of a Python object, your library will have to first acquire the global interpreter lock (GIL). You may as well, and probably should, write a C extension module using Python's C API.

Comment: Yup it works correctly now. You should actually post an answer and not just a comment so I can assign the answer to you. The fact that I need to keep a reference in python feels like a waste of space; is there a work around to this? Maybe both programs could share a common list/array object. As for the C extension module, isn't the code above a very simple C extension module?

Comment: Never mind I just discovered `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF`.

Comment: The `Py_DECREF` and `Py_XDECREF` macros call the type's `tp_dealloc` when the reference count reaches 0. You need to be holding the GIL for this. If I were you I'd just write a real [extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html).